# Object methods assigned to variables or function arguments fail when invoked

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I'm learning javascript right now, seems like beautiful functional language to me, it is wonderful move from PHP, I should have done this earlier. Although, I cannot figure this one out:

```
var v1 = (/[abc]/).test;
v1('a');
```

says `test method called on incompatible undefined`, I'm trying to store the test method of that regex into variable and invoke it later.

but it works with my own functions:

```
function foo(){
    return 'I\'m foo';
}

var f = foo;
f(); // returns I'm foo
```

It should work on methods too, since functions are just methods of parent object anyway, right?

Ultimately, the reason I'm trying this is to be able to write something like this:

```
var a = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
a.every( (/[abc]/).test );
```

to check each array member against that regex.

Why doesn't this work? Is it limitation in passing built-in functions around? Or am I just doing something wrong?

PS: If you grind your teeth now and muffling something about bad practices, screw good practices, I'm just playing. But I'd like to hear about them too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it works with my own functions

You are not using `this` inside the function. Consider this example:

```
var obj = {
    foo: 42,
    bar: function() {
        alert(this.foo);
    }
};
var f = obj.bar;
f(); // will alert `undefined`, not `42`
```

> It should work on methods too, since functions are just methods of parent object anyway, right?

"Method" is just a colloquial term for a function assigned to a property on object. And functions are standalone values. There is no connection to the object a function is assigned to. How would this even be possible, since a function could be assigned to multiple objects?

> Why doesn't this work?

What `this` refers to inside a function is determined at **run time**. So if you assign the function to a variable and call it later

```
var v1 = (/[abc]/).test;
v1('a');
```

`this` inside the function will refer to `window`, not to the regular expression object.

What you can do is use [`.bind` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to explicitly bind `this` to a specific value:

```
var a = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var pattern = /[abc]/;
a.every(pattern.test.bind(pattern));
```

Note though that since `.bind` returns a function, the only advantage over using a function expression is that it is a tad shorter to write.

---

> Is it limitation in passing built-in functions around?

No, the problem exists for every method/function because that's how functions work. The nice thing about built-in functions though is that they often explicitly tell you when `this` is referring to the wrong type of object (by throwing an error).

---

[**Learn more about `this`.**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Comment: Note that in strict mode, `this` would have been undefined.

Comment: I just found there's second argument in every, doing exactly what I wanted... `[1, 321, 123].every(RegExp.prototype.test, /^\d+$/); // true`

Answer (score 3):

If you store just a method, it does not carry with it a reference to your object - it just stores a reference to the `.test` method, but no particular object.  Remember, a method is "just" a property on an object and storing a reference to a method doesn't bind it to that object, it just stores a reference to the method.

To invoke that method on a particular object, you have to call it with that object.

You can make your own function that calls the method on the desired object like this:

```
var v1 = function(x) {
    return /[abc]/.test(x);
}
```

Then, when you do this:

```
v1('a');
```

It will execute the equivalent of this in your function:

```
/[abc]/.test('a');
```

---

But, it isn't entirely clear why you're doing that as you could also just define the regex and call .test() on it several times:

```
var myRegex = /[abc]/;
console.log(myRegex.test('a'));
console.log(myRegex.test('b'));
console.log(myRegex.test('z'));
```

Comment: I know about anonymous functions, but I was hoping to do it without wrapping it in function, since jQuery by itself is function-ception wrapping madness.

Comment: @enrey—That wrapping stems from a philosophy of not modifying objects you don't own, which means don't modify host or built–in objects. That is considered a good thing as it means your code will play nicely with other people's code (provided they have taken the same approach).

Comment: @enrey - You HAVE to create another function that ties your method call to the proper object.  You can either do it yourself like this or you can use `.bind()` and have the framework do it for you.  FYI, `.bind()` does exactly the same thing as this (creates a function wrapper that binds the object and method call together) so it's basically the same.  In either case, for a method like this to work, it has to be called in the form `object.method()`.  You can't just call `method()` and expect it to have the right object associated with it.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks for the info, good to know. I find the `.bind()` way bit easier to read, as it doesn't clobber the code with another lambda when it's supposed to be one liner.

Comment: @enrey - just make sure `.bind()` is supported in all browsers you care about (not supported in IE 8) or use a shim.

Comment: @jfriend00 that's important for me! Ok, so I'm gonna wrap it in function and upvote your answer. It's a shame, cause I got a nice, tiny, visually narrow array of conditions, it's going to look really ugly.

Answer (score 1):

The `test` function expects `this` to be a regular expression. The expression `/[abc]/.test` gives an unbound function (it does not remember that it belongs to `/[abc]/`). When you invoke it like you do, `this` will be `undefined` and the function will fail.

You can use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to make the function remember the object it belongs to:

```
var v1 = /[abc]/.test.bind(/[abc]/);
```

or

```
var v1 = RegExp.prototype.test.bind(/[abc]/);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your reference to the method has lost its knowledge of what it was a method of.
This isn't so much good practice as just the way JS works.

You can do:

```
var v1 = /[abc]/;
v1.test('a');
```

If you must encapsulate the test method, then you could do:

```
var v1 = function(str){
    return /[abc]/.test(str);
};
v1('a');
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is an acceptable solution, but you can do:

```
v1 = function(exp) { return (/[abc]/).test(exp); }
v1('a');
```